# php msqli moving records from one database to another

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm trying to copy records from one database to another. Both are at localhost with same credentials, only db name is different.
From PhpMyAdmin I can do that using and it's working fine:

```
INSERT INTO warszawa.typy_pojazdow (typ, nazwa)
       SELECT type, description from rfid.vehicle_types
```

From php level i don't know how to run that query on both objects in the same time:

```
    $polaczenie = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
    $polaczenie2 = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name2);

    if ($polaczenie->connect_errno!=0)
    {
        echo "Error: ".$polaczenie->connect_errno;
    }
    else
    {
        $select = $polaczenie && $polaczenie2->query("INSERT INTO warszawa.typy_pojazdow (typ, nazwa ) SELECT type, description from rfid.vehicle_types");
    }
```

Please help

Comment: why are you passing 2 connections to the query?

Comment: `mysqli_error($connection_???)` have to say?

Comment: You don't need two connections. Just use one connection and specify the databases explicitly, just like you do in PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 connections if the same $db_user has access to both databases.

```
$polaczenie = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
if ($polaczenie->connect_errno!=0)
{
        echo "Error: ".$polaczenie->connect_errno;
}
else
{
   $select = $polaczenie->query("INSERT INTO warszawa.typy_pojazdow (typ, nazwa) SELECT type, description from rfid.vehicle_types");
}
```